# DBUnit dataset - insert UTC timestamp

Tags: java, jpa, h2, dbunit

Suppose we have a simple dataset for unit tests:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <my_entity
        id="1"
        start_date="2020-10-18 17:00:00 +0000"
    />
</dataset>
```

where `start_date` maps to an `Instant` field in the entity object, and a `TIMESTAMP` column in the database (h2 - for testing).

The problem is: this does not result in UTC timestamp of "2020-10-18T17:00:00Z" being put into the test database!
What ends up there is "2020-10-18T16:00:00Z", i.e. the data loader assumes that the provided date is not UTC, but daylight-saving-time at 0 offset from UTC, which is one hour later. If you change 18th October to e.g. 27th, during winter-time, the hours match.

How do I load proper UTC timestamps in the dataset, without worrying if it's summer or winter?

Comment: In H2, the `TIMESTAMP(9) WITH TIME ZONE` data type should be used to store the `Instant` values and they will be fine **if your persistence layer will pass them to H2 directly as is and will read them directly**; H2 has native support for `Instant`. Your persistence layer most likely does some incorrect conversion. (`TIMESTAMP` data type doesn't have time zone offset information and it can't be reliably used for timestamps near DST or other transitions.)